# Change <svg> height using passed data and spring

Tags: reactjs

I'm React beginner. I tried and searched hours but I still don't get it.

I got (props) from `App.js` as a boolean. Pressed button or not.

I want:
If false, I want to change svg height to 300px, else to 20px. it should be animated. How to bind animation with spring?

Should I make const like navAnimation?

this is App.js

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring';
import Subject from "./components/Subject";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import './components/event.js';

const App = () => {

    const [isNavOpen, setNavOpen] = useState(false);
    const navAnimation = useSpring({
        height : isNavOpen ? 0 : 50,
        opacity : isNavOpen ? 0 : 1
    })

    return(
        <div className="App">
            <div className="sidebar">
                <Sidebar isOpen={isNavOpen} />
                <button onClick={() => setNavOpen(!isNavOpen)}>open</button>    
            </div>
            <div className="main">
                <Subject />    
                <Nav style={navAnimation} />
            </div>  
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and this is Sidebar.js

```js
const Sidebar = (props) => {

    return( 
        <div id="sidebar">
            lorem ipsum
            <svg width="300" height="300">
                <rect width="10vh" height="20" x="10" y="10" />
            </svg>
        </div>                      
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change between two values based on a boolean, a ternary can be used.

```js
boolean ? ValueIfTrue : ValueIfFalse
```

---

You can embed expressions in jsx with curly braces. Based on the name of the prop key, the height will be set to 300 or 20. I would recommend setting some kind of unit rather than just 300, i.e. 300px.

Good luck with the rest of what you are building

```
const Sidebar = (props) => {

return( 
    <div id="sidebar">
        lorem ipsum
        <svg width="300" height={this.props.keyFromApp ? "300": "20"}>
            <rect width="10vh" height="20" x="10" y="10" />
        </svg>
    </div>  
);
}
```

---

Finally you need to make sure the child rerenders when the parents values change. Currently the parents variables aren't states. This means that if a parents variables change no rerendering of the child components

```js
const App = () => {

const [isNavOpen, setNavOpen] = useState(true);
const navAnimation = useSpring({
    height : isNavOpen ? 0 : 50,
    opacity : isNavOpen ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: thanks for you answer.
but I still can't solve it. it goes to 300px at first but it doesn't get back to 20px when i press the button. I'm keep searching and trying.
thanks!

Comment: Try _use setState(true)_ instead of use setState(false). If the variables are stateful, it should cause a rerender of the child class when the parent classes states change.